# Understanding correlation between different filters?

Tags: correlation, data-visualization

I'm not involved in mathematics or data science very much, but I want to do some computation on a rental dataset that I have.

I currently filter different listings that do and do not have whatever amenities I select.

How can I compute correlation of whether the amenities increase or decrease price?

Comment: If your question has been answered to your satisfaction, you can accept an answer by clicking the check mark under the voting arrows.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you probably want a regression model, where the dependent variable is price and the independent variables are amenities. The simplest kinds of regression models should be discussed in any introductory text on data analysis, statistics, or machine learning, which you should avail yourself of if you want to analyze data.